# Selenium webdriver.Remote() can't click on elements

Tags: django, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

### Situation

I'm using the **Selenium Remote webdriver** to do my tests on a **Django project**. I have several Docker containers, which is why I needed to use the Remote driver.

In my test, my Selenium configuration is as follows

```py
# Inside setUp() method from Django's TestCase
self.firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://develop-tandem-marianao-selenium:4444",
    options=self.firefox_options,
)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

### Problem

Thing is, the Selenium and Django project containers are connected properly and I am able to perform tests, but whenever I try the `click()` method on any element, I get the error

```
Element <...> could not be scrolled into view
```

However, by searching around I found out that doing

```py
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

instead does work. I've read somewhere that it might be a problem that some part of the website is not loaded yet when Selenium attempts to `click()`, but that still doesn't tell me what to do.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've also tried forcing the test to wait (with `time.sleep()`) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try looking into webdriver waits for the element to be clickable or using the scroll into view built in function.

Comment: I tried some waits and actions and it didn't seem to work. I then tried to change the Firefox driver for the Chrome driver and everything worked fine, so I think I'm going to just do that. Thanks for the input though, @ArundeepChohan !